# Test the convergence of series $\sum \frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}$ when $x\neq0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $ t_n=\frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}$ and using root test
$$ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} {t_n}^{\frac{1}{n}}=  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{a^n}{a^n+x^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\big(1+(\frac{x}{a})^n\big)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$
Now I am stuck, I don't know how to evaluate this limit

Comment: What’s a definition of $e^x$?

Comment: @R.Jackson Thanks for replying. But I don't get it. The exponent $\frac{1}{n}$ in the denominator doesn't tends to infinity so how can we use the definition of $e^x$.

Answer (score 4):

$$x=a \implies t_n=\frac 12 $$
$$\implies \sum t_n \text{ diverges}$$

$$|x|<|a|\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}t_n=1$$
$$\implies \sum t_n\text{ diverges}$$

$$|x|>|a|\implies t_n\sim (\frac ax)^n$$
$$\implies \sum t_n \text{ converges}$$